# Chat top bar styling is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat, top-bar

The most recent rollout of the [new top bar design](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/topbar/) broke the styling for the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) top bar - can this be fixed, please?

[image: screenshot of the unstyled top bar]

Comment: Looks retro me. It is fine.

Comment: I assume this is now [tag:status-completed], the topbar is fixed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has now been fixed. Chat was using the old *old* topbar (two design iterations ago), with the html being rendered on the chat side, but the css being pulled from the core codebase. Short version is - we tested this locally during development and it worked, but due to some legacy/tech debt shenanigans it stopped working in prod when we deployed.

We've restored the old styles to chat directly so we can remove them from the core codebase entirely.