# The site icons in all the dropdowns in the top bar on the chat page seem to have... disappeared?

Tags: bug, status-review, chat, stack-exchange-button, icons

This is how it looks like on any page<sup>1</sup> *except* the chat page:

[image: Image of Stack Exchange menu with site icons included]

The site icons are visible here, but on the **chat** page<sup>2</sup>, these icons seem to have disappeared (the alignment is messed up as well):

[image: Image of Stack Exchange menu on the chat page with site icons missing]

This also happens in the reputation and inbox dropdowns.

I'm using Chrome (version 102.0.5005.115) on Windows 11.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The dropdown is accessible by clicking on the icon in the rightmost corner of the top nav.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> This can be accessed by clicking on the Stack Exchange button in the leftmost corner of the top nav on the chat page.</sup>

Comment: I can reproduce this with Safari regardless of which site I access the chat page from, including Stack Overflow, Meta, ELL.

Comment: I can also repro this when I force Chrome on Android to request the desktop version.

Comment: I miss the old top bar :(

Comment: @nicael web archive.

Comment: Looks like the [recent fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377572/chat-top-bar-styling-is-broken) added this new bug. :(

Comment: Regarding bounty: waste of rep, it's already in review, really nothing more we can do. (I place bounties on bugs/requests without status at all, trying to draw the staff to review them, at least.)

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who can't wait for 6 to 8 weeks it will take for this to get fixed, here is a userscript to repair the broken window. It is as simple as adding the class `s-topbar` to the `topbar-wrapper` once the site-switcher is loaded.

[Code on Github](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/blob/master/fix-chat-icons.user.js) |
[Direct install](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/raw/master/fix-chat-icons.user.js)

#### Code for the curious

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fix chat icons
// @namespace    https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene
// @version      0.1
// @description  Fix chat icons in site switcher
// @author       rene
// @match        https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/
// @match        https://chat.stackexchange.com/
// @match        https://chat.stackoverflow.com/
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=stackexchange.com
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=stackoverflow.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    (new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        document.querySelector('.topbar-wrapper').classList.add('s-topbar');
    })).observe(document.querySelector('.js-topbar-dialog-corral'), {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
})();
```

[Visit Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) for more awesome fixes or share your own!