# Inbox and reputation overlays don't open for Teams users

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stack-overflow-for-teams

On Stack Overflow and other network sites, when I attempt to open the inbox or reputation window, something opens very briefly but immediately closes.

[image: Animated gif of inbox not opening]

This occurs on Chrome and Safari. Other users in chat confirmed that this occurs for them in Internet Explorer.

I am a member of two Stack Overflow Teams.

Comment: This doesn't occur for me, on windows chrome, light mode

Comment: Same issue on Vivaldi. Both dark and light mode.

Comment: Able to reproduce as well on Edge. As a temporary workaround, one can view these overlays on stackexchange.com, the chat sites, or Area 51 {though the top bar [doesn't render correctly there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377733/the-top-bar-on-area-51-is-malformed)).

Comment: We are currently experiencing an outage with Teams and any accounts connected to Teams will not be able to access those popups until it is fixed. https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/8e96da33-e677-45d2-947b-b1766b99781e

Comment: Links `https://stackexchange.com/users/<userid>?tab=reputation` and `https://stackexchange.com/users/<userid>?tab=inbox` still work.

Comment: Ok, it's started working for me now.

Comment: @animuson Why does that page still use the old name of "Channels" for the product?

Comment: @Sonic Whoever created the incident used Channels instead of Teams. _shrugs_

Answer (score 1):

From a [comment by animuson ♦️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379710/inbox-and-reputation-overlays-dont-open-for-teams-users#comment1266899_379710), there was:

> .... an outage with Teams and any accounts connected to Teams will not be able to access those popups until it is fixed.

This issue has now been fixed.

Link to the aforementioned incident: [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/8e96da33-e677-45d2-947b-b1766b99781e)