# The top bar inbox and reputation buttons won't expand

Tags: bug, top-bar

[image: Part of the SE top bar. attempts are made to click on the inbox and reputation box]

Yeah, so our inbox and reputation boxes don't show anything. They open and just close. This is.. suboptimal. Could we get this fixed please?

Comment: ninja'ed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379710/inbox-and-reputation-overlays-dont-open#379710 ;)

Comment: hm, with animated gifs

Comment: Great minds think alike? =)

Comment: quite, If you hadn't had them, I might have closed the other way :D